# Do the prime ideals that determine the Krull dimension of a ring have to be proper?

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I have recently been introduced to the Krull dimension of rings, and the definition I am using is consistent with that on wikipedia: the Krull dimension of a ring $R$ is "the supremum of the lengths of all chains of prime ideals in $R$".

However the only definitions I can find do not specify whether the prime ideals that can be used in said chains are proper or not.

Wikipedia claims that $\mathbb{Z}$ has Krull dimension 1. Would ${0}$ $\subseteq $ $<2>$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{Z}$ not be a counterexample giving a chain of length $2$, assuming we count from $0$? Why is clarification on proper ideals not given? Is it an obvious assumption that the ring itself is not included?

Comment: Prime ideals are proper unless one really wants them not to be, and then you have to be explicit about it. (Otherwise "maximal ideals" are not that interesting…)

Comment: This is a convention relation to the fact that the zero ring is not a field, for example: it makes the statement «the quotient of a commutative ring by a maximal ideal is a field» true.

Comment: Prime ideals are always proper.

Comment: Indeed they are. I'm not sure how I went for so long not realising that this was embedded into the definition of the prime ideal itself. Thanks.